# How to pass a name as a variable from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables. One which has names of managers and a null column which i want to insert data into from table 1 ( which has a hierarchy). I figured our the insert piece but instead of using the exact name i want to pass the name from table 2 into table 1 using a variable so its dynamic. please let me know if this can be done and how to do this.

```
UPDATE direct_manager_report 
Set Manager_level_number = 
(Select 'Manager_Level_0' from manager_hierarchy where level_0_manager_name = 'ABC'
UNION
Select 'Manager_Level_1' from manager_hierarchy where level_0_manager_name < > 'ABC' AND level_1_manager_name = 'ABC'
UNION
Select 'Manager_Level_2' from manager_hierarchy where level_1_manager_name < > 'ABC' AND level_2_manager_name = 'ABC'
UNION
Select 'Manager_Level_3' from manager_hierarchy where level_2_manager_name < > 'ABC' AND level_3_manager_name = 'ABC'
)
Where full_name = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Where will you get the names from?  And does this code get you your desired update as is?

Comment: `'Manager_Level_0'` is a constant string. Did you mean a column named `Manager_Level_0` instead? Also, I don't think you can update a field with a query that has more than 1 row (and this won't really make sense either). I presume you want to replace `'ABC'` with `direct_manager_report.someColumn` (which will probably work just like that).

Comment: Manager Level 0 is the 1st column in the hierarchy which goes upto 14. What i am trying to accomplish is passing the manager name from table 2 (direct_manageR_report) to table 1 (manager_hierarchy) through a variable and find the highest level the manager sits at in the hierarchy. in the above sql statement, ABC sits at level 3, which it will pickup and populate in the direct_manager_report table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work if you just want to have one spot to put the manager's name, assuming the query returns desired results aside from having to hard-code 'ABC' everywhere:

```
DECLARE @man_name AS VARCHAR(50) = 'ABC'
UPDATE direct_manager_report 
Set Manager_level_number = 
(Select 'Manager_Level_0' from manager_hierarchy where level_0_manager_name = @man_name
UNION
Select 'Manager_Level_1' from manager_hierarchy where level_0_manager_name < > @man_name AND level_1_manager_name = @man_name
UNION
Select 'Manager_Level_2' from manager_hierarchy where level_1_manager_name < > @man_name AND level_2_manager_name = @man_name
UNION
Select 'Manager_Level_3' from manager_hierarchy where level_2_manager_name < > @man_name AND level_3_manager_name = @man_name
)
Where full_name = @man_name
```

You could populate the @man_name variable via a select statement:
DECLARE @man_name AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @man_name = (SELECT FROM)

If you want to loop through a number of names you could use a cursor, or you could forget the variable and use a JOIN in your update.

Comment: got this errorORA-06550: line 1, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@man_name" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: PL/SQL might have different syntax, my answer was for MS SQL Server, since question wasn't tagged.  Might have time to look at it later.

Comment: i am using oracle sql developer.

Comment: and i do want it pass a long list of names, so looking or join is required. not sure how do i do the join for a repetitive run